How do you debug and learn mod_rewrite?
While developing the web, I often use .htaccess, so I am learning about mod_rewrite.
When debugging mod_rewrite, I wish the change status would be output on the screen like code, but I have difficulty learning because I don't think I did.
The site that I'm testing is
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/
Ida.
How do you guys learn mod_rewrite and debug?

The rewriting module comes with a feature called "rewrite logging". Take a look at the documentation to learn how to use it. The feature offers insight into what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine on a step by step level.

Set your LogLevel to the highest trace, you will see a LOT of details.

@arkascha thany you
After setting the rewrite log in the config file, I looked at the error.log and confirmed that it was debuged.
Another question is, only browser url is debugged, but js, css request url is not debugged, is there any way to debug js, css request url?

JS and CSS requests would also be logged, just like any other request, unless... the responses are cached "locally" or you have a frontend proxy/CDN that manages your static assets and the requests aren't actually reaching your server?

Question is what is actually meant here with "js, css request url is not debugged". If that refers to logging requests for js, css ressources then those should get logged like any other request (unless they are locally cached, es @MrWhite states). If that refers to actual debugging of the code however, then no, RequestLogging is not a debugger, it only logs requests.
